# Get JMS message receipt time

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq, java-ee-6, mq

Is there any method/api to get JMS message receipt time (Not delivery, Not publish timestamp) ? Or i need to fix it manually in `onMessage(Message msg)` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, there is no "receive timestamp" in JMS api, some more specific JMS implementations may provide this feature, however if you want to stay on specification level - you need to put down this data yourself.